# Android annotations framework equivalence for iOS development

Tags: android, ios, android-annotations

Most of my android apps take as its core [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org).

I can find equivalences for [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) on [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), [SwiftEventBus](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus) for [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) for [ReactiveJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) for [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), and so on. But I can’t find a framework such powerful and complete like Android Annotations for iOS.

Do you know any equivalent framework?